# How to 301 redirect through .htaccess

Tags: redirect

What I want to achieve : redirect all traffic 301 redirect from olddomain.com to newdomain.com

olddomain.com/whateverpage.html should redirect to the root of newdomain.com

Right now olddomain.com/whateverpage.html redirects to newdomain.com/whateverpage.html which results in a 404. I need all traffic to go to newdomain.com.

This is the .htaccess I'm using.

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: What does this have to do with *programming*?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This didn't work, it's  not redirecting anything with this .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, if your DNS provider supports it you can create URL 301 Redirect records in `olddomain.com`'s DNS zone that redirects traffic to `newdomain.com`.

For example, to redirect all URLs you need two DNS records in `olddomain.com`:

```
Host         Record type            Address
*            URL 301 Redirect       www.newdomain.com
@            URL 301 Redirect       www.newdomain.com
```

---

### How this works

The DNS record type "URL 301 Redirect" doesn't actually exist. To implement this functionality, your DNS provider will create a DNS `A` record in your domain that points to a web server they maintain.  When visitors type `www.olddomain.com/somepage` the provider's web server will respond with HTTP status code 301 ("Moved Permanently") and direct the client's browser to `newdomain.com`.

This method has several advantages:

1. You don't need to pay for or maintain a web server for `olddomain.com`
2. The full URL requested by the client browser (`www.olddomain.com/somepage`) is preserved through the redirect